# vb.net multi dimensional arrays

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

net right now regarding multi dimensional array my problem is i want to get the nearest numbers for example my input was 13000, the nearest number will be 11667 and then it will subtract it by 13000, then it will multiply by 0.25 and add my 1875.00. here is my code about multidimensional array can you please help me regarding this? i need this in my project thank you in advance

```
    If ComboBox5.Text = "Z" Then
        Dim zero(3, 8) As Double
        Dim row As Double

        Dim col As Double

        'col 1
        zero(0, 0) = 0.0
        zero(1, 0) = 0
        zero(2, 0) = 1

        'col 2
        zero(0, 1) = 0.0
        zero(1, 1) = 0.05
        zero(2, 1) = 0

        'col 3
        zero(0, 2) = 41.67
        zero(1, 2) = 0.1
        zero(2, 2) = 833

        'col 4
        zero(0, 3) = 208.33
        zero(1, 3) = 0.15
        zero(2, 3) = 2500

        'col 5
        zero(0, 4) = 708.33
        zero(1, 4) = 0.2
        zero(2, 4) = 5833

        'col 6
        zero(0, 5) = 1875.0
        zero(1, 5) = 0.25
        zero(2, 5) = 11667

        'col 7
        zero(0, 6) = 4166.67
        zero(1, 6) = 0.3
        zero(2, 6) = 20833

        'col 8
        zero(0, 7) = 10416.67
        zero(1, 7) = 0.32
        zero(2, 7) = 41667


        For row = 0 To 3
            For col = 0 To 8

                If Val(TextBox18.Text) > Val(zero(row, col)) And Val(TextBox18.Text) < Val(zero(row - 1, col + 1)) Then
                    ListView1.Items.Add(zero(row, col))
                End If
            Next
        Next



    End If
```

Comment: `11667` isnt in the list so what makes it the closest?  There are much better collections for look ups than arrays

Answer (score 0):

2D array is not very appropriate to store this kind of data, but here is an example to get you started:

```
    Dim data(,) = {
        {0.0, 0, 1},
        {0.0, 0.05, 0},
        {41.67, 0.1, 833},
        {208.33, 0.15, 2500},
        {708.33, 0.2, 5833},
        {1875.0, 0.25, 11667},
        {4166.67, 0.3, 20833},
        {10416.67, 0.32, 41667}}

    Dim value = 13000 ' Dim value = Val(TextBox18.Text)

    ' data.GetLength(0) is 8, so Enumerable.Range generates the numbers from 0 to 7
    Dim range = Enumerable.Range(0, data.GetLength(0))

    ' .OrderBy orders them by the difference between value and the last column in data
    Dim ordered = range.OrderBy(Function(i) Math.Abs(data(i, 2) - value)) ' 5,4,6,3,2,0,1,7 

    Dim nearestIndex = ordered.First ' 5

    Dim value1 = data(nearestIndex, 0) ' 1875.0
    Dim value2 = data(nearestIndex, 1) ' 0.25
    Dim value3 = data(nearestIndex, 2) ' 11667

    Dim result = (value3 - value) * value2 + value1 ' result = 1541.75
```

Comment: Hi Slai, i have a question, i had change my variable and it looks like this: my input was 13973.88 and the nearest one is 15833 and actually it should be the nearest one is 10000